# Error when releasing NSdate from [NSDateComponents components: fromDate: toDate: options:]

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

Okay so i got this clas called event.

It has a property called eventDate wich is a NSDate. I made a method to return how many years it is since the event date:

```
- (double)yearsSinceEvent {
    double years;

    // Get the system calendar
    NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // Create the NSDates
    NSDate *date1 = self.eventDate; 
    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate  date];


    // Get conversion to months, days, hours, minutes
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];

    years = [conversionInfo year];

    [date1 release];
    [date2 release];

    return years;
}
```

when configuring my tableview cells i do:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d year's ago", [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] yearsSinceEvent]];
```

But this throws this error:

*** __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject(): release of previously deallocated object (0x595bda0) ignored

What am i doing wrong here?

If i dont release date1 and date2 i dont get the error, but the method returns 0..

If i do the yearsSinceEvent code in the cell configuration method instead, and dont release date 1 and date 2 it works..

How should i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not release date1 and date2 because they're already autoreleased. Make sure your eventDate ivar is properly declared as a retained property: it should be `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *eventDate;`

Answer (score 2):

You should not release `date1` and `date2` in this case.
`date2` is created with a factory method and will be autoreleased.
`date1` is something you read from another property WITHOUT retaining it so you should not release that one either or self.eventDate will be released.

[Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

> You take ownership of an object if you
>   create it using a method whose name
>   begins with “alloc” or “new” or
>   contains “copy” (for example, alloc,
>   newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you
>   send it a retain message. You are
>   responsible for relinquishing
>   ownership of objects you own using
>   release or autorelease. Any other time
>   you receive an object, you must not
>   release it.

Comment: Thanks guys! I feel stupid. Should have seen that. copied code and changed it..
I am not shure why i get 0 back when removing the releases thou.. I do think i am retaining the NSDate value.. I'l check when i get back home..

Comment: The reason the method returned 0 was that [conversionInfo year] returns a NSInteger. I Changed my double's to NSIntegers and it worked perfect!